# vscode terminal blurry text

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, blurry

[image]

I did made a new Repo with Gitlab and now I got blurry text in vscode,

I tried some new fonts too use but the blurry text stayed.
I have no idea how too fix too fix the issue, Ive tried too look it up on the web, but I dont come far.

Comment: Show us what the value of `"terminal.integrated.fontFamily"` is in your settings.json

Comment: Terminal › Integrated: Font Family
Controls the font family of the terminal. Defaults to Editor: Font Family's value.

monospace


Thats what I get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, I had too put the gpu acceleration on off

[The Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsSlJ.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).